# How to detect that Windows Firewall is asking user for permission

Tags: windows-firewall

We're working on an application that listens on some ports. We really want to avoid using a proper installer, so we can't open the firewall at that point.

First time the application runs, Windows pops up a dialog, asking the user for permission. At this point, we want to delay execution until the user has clicked yes (or no, for that matter).

At present we use something like:

```
while(FindWindow("Windows Security Alert")) {
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

..which works, but isn't rock solid. As far as i can tell, the [firewall api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't offer this information.

Bonus question: Is there also a way to detect whether the user clicked yes or no?

Comment: IMO it is a design flaw to do this. You should just attempt connection and then possibly reattempt a few more times. If it fails you can then message the user to say possibly their firewall is blocking it.

Comment: Or you could just ask the user to deal with any such dialogs before continuing...

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some code on how to open the filewall port yourself in C# code http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2008/01/controlling-win.html
Of course your app must be running elevated in order to do this.

There are several installers on the web too which offer this functionality. For example (unfortunately not open source): uTorrent's installer.